# Why do we need $N$ large in Marcus $3.21$?

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, discriminant

Exercise $3.21$ of Marcus’ “Number Fields” (an excellent book) has been giving me trouble on and off for a while now. I think I’ve finally got it but I’m suspicious of my solution since it nowhere requires “large $N$“. I would appreciate feedback **and** any suggestions for alternative solutions to the exercise (that does not mean alternative proofs of the theorem, that means alternative proofs that follow the template Marcus suggests). There is also a further result about when this is the *exact* power of $p$ dividing the discriminant (when all ramification indices are coprime with $p$); does anyone know if the strategy of this exercise can be used to prove that as well?

---

The setup: we have a number field $K$ with number ring $R$, a prime integer $p$ and prime factorisation $pR=Q_1^{e_1}Q_2^{e_2}\cdots Q_r^{e_r}$ with inertial degrees $f_1,\cdots,f_r$. Let $n=[K:\Bbb Q]$. There exist $\alpha_{i,j}\in(Q_i^{j-1}\setminus Q_i^j)\prod_{h\neq i}Q_h^N$ and $\beta_{i,k}\in R$ for $1\le i \le r$, $1\le j\le e_i$, $1\le k\le f_i$ such that the set of products $\{\alpha_{i,j}\beta_{i,k}\}$ is a set of $n$ independent elements mod $p$. Here, $N$ is any integer larger than every single $e_i$ but can be chosen as large as please: Marcus **seems to suggest we need a larger choice of $N$** than merely $\max e_\bullet$.

We need to show the discriminant of the $\alpha\beta$ is divisible by $p^{\sum_i(e_i-1)f_i}$. My solution:

Let $L$ be the normal closure of $K/\Bbb Q$ and $Z$ any prime of $L$ over $p$. If $j>1$ then any product $\gamma=\alpha_{i,j}\beta_{i,k}\cdot\alpha_{i’,j’}\beta_{i’,k’}$ will be an element of every prime of $K$ over $p$, so any $\sigma\in\mathsf{Gal}(L;\Bbb Q)$ will satisfy: $\sigma^{-1}(Z)$ is a prime of $L$ over $p$ so $\gamma\in\sigma^{-1}(Z)\cap R\subset\sigma^{-1}(Z)$ so $\sigma(\gamma)\in Z$.

It follows from additive closure of $Z$ that $\mathrm{Tr}^K_{\Bbb Q}(\gamma)\in Z\cap\Bbb Z=p\Bbb Z$. It then follows all the $\sum_i(e_i-1)f_i$ rows of the matrix of traces of such $\gamma$ with $j>1$ are divisible by $p$, so the determinant is divisible by $p^{\sum_i(e_i-1)f_i}$.

Is this legitimate? Can it be improved to show the stronger theorem, that this is the exact power of $p$ dividing the discriminant if all $e_i$ are indivisible by $p$? Many thanks.

Comment: This looks correct to me… but I’m not sure how to use this approach to derive the correct exponent in tamely ramified cases, though. Part of the problem, I think, is that it’s not easy to individually manipulate the $e_i$ (and use the fact that they’re not divisible by $p$). I would rather have worked locally (by completing at every $Q_i$ separately) than globally…

Comment: @Aphelli Unfortunately I know nothing about local methods in number theory